# Проблема с выгрузкой данных с помощью MSSQL 2017 c сервера Postgressql

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Возникла следующая проблема, есть MSSQL 2017 c залинкованным сервером Postgressql. При попытке сделать простой запрос, выдает ошибку: OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked server 'PG' returned data that does not match expected data length for column '[MSDASQL].Request'. The (maximum) expected data length is 510, while the returned data length is 11808.
Не могу понять в чем дело, помогите разобраться.
Сам запрос:

```
select top 1 * from 
openquery([PG], 
'
SELECT  *
FROM (
       SELECT
         date,
         login,
         request                                                         AS "Request",
         response                                                        AS "Response",
         exc                                                             AS "Exception"
       FROM logs
        ) AS result
WHERE date >= ''20190416''
ORDER BY date DESC
')
```

Comment: Похоже, Вы упираетесь в `MaxVarcharSize=255;` в строке подключения (уж больно 510 на 255*2 похоже...). Попробуйте установить `MaxLongVarcharSize=достаточно много;` и `TextAsLongVarchar=1;`. Ну и вообще там где-то рядом пошаманить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда то сталкивался с этой проблемой помогло явное указание типов данных

```
    select top 1 * from 
    openquery([PG], 
    '
    SELECT  *
    FROM (
       SELECT
         date,
         cast(login as nchar(10)), 
         cast(request as nchar(...) )                            AS "Request",
         cast(response  as nchar(...))                            AS "Response",
         cast(exc as nchar(...))                                  AS "Exception"
       FROM logs
        ) AS result
   WHERE date >= ''20190416''
   ORDER BY date DESC
   ')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!